# How to make minitest stop execution on failure?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, minitest

I am using Minitest as the runner for my functional tests, using Selenium as the driver to run the browser. Each test is modeled as MiniTest::Unit::TestCase.

Minitest reports summary of execution when it completes executing all tests. The Exceptions that were encountered are also printed towards the end of the execution. I find it difficult to debug when something unexpected fails as the context of execution is lost. The exceptions I am running into are not deterministic.

Is there a way to make Minitest runner to stop execution of tests on exception or assertion failure?

I am using minitest (2.11.2) and ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]

Answer (score 4):

try `rails test -f` will do it. It means abort test run of first failure or error.

Comment: This option shows up in the help text in Rails 5 but doesn't appear to do anything.

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean to have a "fast fail" option available. I found the [fail_fast for minitest (Test::Unit): Immediate backtrace & exit](http://www.opinionatedprogrammer.com/2010/12/minitest-test-unit-immediate-backtrace-and-exit-on-failure/) article, but that's out of date (still covers what can be done). I think you'll need to monkeypatch your testing library to enable this option. I found a Gist showing how to [add a simple fail-fast option to `minitest/turn/minitest-rails`](https://gist.github.com/dup2/6160098) so that might get you on the right track. I understand your problem is to do with the first article I've referenced:

> When I run the Test::Unit suite in my Ruby on Rails 3 project through
>   `rake test` and a test is failing, the default behavior is to just
>   print “F” or “E”, keep running until all the tests are finished (while
>   I twiddle my thumbs), and only then print out a stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

As I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29991323/388928), I found a gem for: [minitest-fail-fast](https://github.com/teoljungberg/minitest-fail-fast). It works with Rails 4.2 and Minitest 5.6.1

Answer (score 1):

It does not directly answer the question, but might be very useful.

You could use `pry-rescue` gem so that your tests will launch a pry session whenever something goes wrong. All you have to do is to add the gem into your Gemfile:

```rb
group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry-rescue'
end
```

Then launch your tests with the following flag:

```sh
PRY_RESCUE_RAILS=1 rails test rails test test/integration/agendas_test.rb
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `-f`.

In pure ruby, as you ask for, this means `ruby <file> -f`.

In rails, this means `rails test -f`.

Minitest will check the terminal's arguments for the `-f` flag, so how you call it appears to not be relevant to the `-f` flag.