# Possible to "fail fast" when running rake test w/ minitest 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

Is it possible to configure 'rake test' to stop running tests as soon as it hits a failure/exception?

My setup:

- Rails 4.1
- Minitest 5.3.4
- Tapout (for formatting)

I'd like to start the test suite and immediately stop if a test fails -- the default behavior is to keep running all the tests which, in some cases, is too much data (especially one small bug causes a ton of tests to suddenly fail.)

I had a nice little setup going with the older version of Minitest (4.x) and the Turn gem by following this gist: ([Add a simple fail-fast option to minitest/turn/minitest-rails](https://gist.github.com/dup2/6160098)), but I'm working on a new Rails 4.1 app right now and Turn isn't compatible with Minitest 5 (yet).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why do you need turn for this?

Comment: This gist I linked to (and what I had working originally) was a modification to Turn, I think?  I don't think it's needed, strictly-speaking.

Comment: so if you have the contents of that file in your spec helper, what happens?  you get an error?

Comment: I believe with Minitest 5 it threw an error.  Alas, I decided that bending Minitest to my will was more work than necessary and I switched over to Rspec, which has, for better or for worse, been a pleasure to use.  Doesn't help answer the question for the benefit of others, I know, but that's where I'm at :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Rails 5, try `rails test -f` will 'fail fast'. It means abort test run of first failure or error if you run `rails test -h`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this new gem with Rails 4.2 and and Minitest 5.6.1: [minitest-fail-fast](https://github.com/teoljungberg/minitest-fail-fast)